# How to revert to the old login screen

Tags: greeter

How can I transform the **ugly** Elementary OS Freya login screen back into the beautiful Luna login screen.  That, for me being picky with design, would put me off using Elementary.  I like the Operating System but the new login screen just puts me off.

---

**EDIT: Added images**

Current **ugly** login screen

[image: Current **ugly** login screen]

Old beautiful login screen

[image]

Comment: Do you have some images to know what screens you are referring to?

Comment: Added the images

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to get the old screen. Both screenshots show `pantheon-greeter` but in different versions - and it's not possible to install older versions on Freya.

It's sad you'd consider to leave elementary OS because of the new greeter though.

Comment: That's really annoying- the new one just looks rubbish.  If there ever was a way in the future to select the old greeter as an option I may return to Elementary.

Comment: @Tim no, not really. You cannot theme `pantheon-greeter`. Greeters already are some kind of theme for LightDM. It's possible to write your own greeter or update the `pantheon-greeter` back from Luna to work with Freya, but there is no easy solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to download the code to the old greeter and compile it yourself, though I cannot guarantee that it would actually work.

Perhaps, if you are proficient enough with coding, you can fork and update the old greeter to work with newer releases.